# Windows store app: Changing Background image Dynamically from code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Im working on a weather app and i want to change the background image dynamically depending on weather its sunny, cloudy and so on. I set the Background image for all the pages from App.xaml.cs as following:

```
  rootFrame.Background = new ImageBrush
            {
                Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill,
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/blueSky.jpg") }
            };
```

I set the image in App.xaml.cs so all the pages gets the same image, and i dont need to load the image everytime. Full code of App.xaml.cs:

```
 sealed partial class App : Application
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used when the application is launched to open a specific file, to display
    /// search results, and so forth.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;


        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();


            // Her we set the application background Image for all pages
            rootFrame.Background = new ImageBrush
            {
                Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill,
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/blueSky.jpg") }
            };
            weather.Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "appFrame");


            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                await weather.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        await weather.Common.SuspensionManager.SaveAsync();
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

This works fine for 1 image, but i cant auto change the image. Any ideas?

Comment: You are only changing the image when the application is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the code where you get the weather from a web service?  In that code, get the current weather and then, based on the forecast, set the background picture.